# Captain America said "if you get killed, walk it off!" How to understand "walk it off"?

Tags: translation

*The Avengers 2* just hit China yesterday. The official translation of the line "If you get killed, walk it off!" is "Someone is trying to kill you, run, run for your life" (This is the English version of that Chinese translation). Such a nonsense. But how to understand the original English sentence correctly?

Comment: The people at the translation office really blew this one. I guess they'll just have to run, run for their lives.

Comment: [A rather morbid "walk it off"](https://youtu.be/6i5M6sTe_9Q?t=40s)

Comment: People die when they are killed.

Comment: A vivid example http://9gag.com/gag/aEwYdjM/walking-it-off-like-a-boss

Comment: @blancocayo (It's a meme.)

Comment: My first thought was to walk off being drunk. Comparing death to being drunk is just as funny as comparing it to a minor injury!

Comment: @Veedrac For those who don't understand why this comment is being upvoted: [see here](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/people-die-if-they-are-killed)

Comment: Can we have the Chinese please ? (simplified is OK).

Answer (score 168, accepted):

"Walk it off" is a flippant response for when someone is hurt or injured. It generally means that they should continue as if nothing had happened (that is, they should continue walking), and that they'll be back in good health after a while. An example might be if you took a bad step and hurt your ankle slightly; it may well be better to continue walking until the pain subsides instead of stopping.

In the Captain America example he is joking that even dying should not stop you from winning; you should pretend that nothing happened and keep fighting.

Comment: This answer is worded so much better.

Comment: If you have a leg cramp, "walk it off!" might even be good advice, as walking or stretching will relieve the cramp more quickly then lying on the ground holding it.

Comment: I always enjoy the similar phrase _"Rub some dirt on it and get back in the game"_  Usually it's not spoken in the serious sense (no one expects you to rub dirt on an injury) but is meant to evoke a sense of toughness

Comment: Note that this can also be used outside of sports (although perhaps not as often).  For example, if you approach that cute girl/guy at the bar and they reject you, rather than feel despondant, you can 'walk it off' and 'get back in the game'.

Comment: I think the "sense of toughness" @watcher mentioned is important to get the full meaning of the joke.  It's a tough guy in authority telling the team to "tough it up", and that he won't accept excuses, including (jokingly) death.  It's funny because the way he is phrasing the toughness (not even accepting death as an excuse for poor performance) is extreme to the point of being ridiculous.

Comment: never heard the expression in the UK. shrug it off yes. walk it off no! shrug it off is very common, walk it off, never heard it once!

Comment: obviously it is a US expression. it's a new one to me.

Comment: @ufomorace I'm British and have heard it plenty of times :) Maybe just different dialects.

Comment: @HerrPink I figured it could be a recent trend buzzword, same as chill out which is probably since 1980 or so, alont with the word cool. shrug it off is 3.5 times more common that walk it off, I don't recall hearing walk it off on TV, perhaps i didnt realize it was an expression rather than a sentence. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shrug+it+off%2Cwalk+it+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshrug%20it%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalk%20it%20off%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Walking it off usually goes well in Oregon Trail…

Comment: "Walk it off" is a common expression on American sports fields. Captain America seemed to also be saying that death shouldn't be overly feared, a recurring theme in the film's dialogue. (I saw it less than an hour ago, in Seoul, but missed the Korean translation of that line. Incidentally people seemed very amused by the scenes that took place here.)

Comment: The best example would be the Monty Python's Dark Knight: "it's just a flesh wound". That is real toughness.

Comment: Why is this upvoted so much when it doesn't explain the "walk" in "walk in off" at all?!!

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I feel that the 'walk' part is metaphorical, particularly in the example given in the question.

Comment: @HerrPink:   Yes, it is metaphorical in this case, but the answer doesn't explain the term at all, which is the question.    For the Monte Python example a few comments up, it would be like if someone didn't know what a "flesh wound" is and the answer was "The character claims they are fine" instead of explaining "a flesh wound is a minor injury to just skin and no vital organs, so the character is humorously ignoring the obviously grave nature of the dismemberment."    OK the example isn't perfect but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: Fair enough @ ThePopMachine. I have added a sentence to help clarify the literal meaning of the phrase..

Answer (score 70):

When one is injured, for example in an athletic competition, the advice might be to get up and walk around in pain until the pain subsides and one is again able to participate.  This is opposed to one's probable inclination to lie on the ground until one feels able to continue.  "Walking it off" is seen as a tougher and perhaps quicker way of dealing with the injury.

Being killed, here, is treated just as any other injury, as if it were possible to recover from death.

Comment: A similar common expression is "Shake it off".

Comment: As my comment beneath the original post suggests, "walk it off" is also used in sports settings to advise players to clear their minds of a blunder they just committed. But you are certainly correct that, in the context of the OP's movie quote, the emphasis is on toughing one's way through an injury.

Comment: "Find a way to endure the pain, because it's not going to stop."

Comment: Practical advice in sports is to lie down even when it might be just a minor injury until doctors arrives and properly inspects you. Probable inclination in sports is usually opposite of lying on the ground, due to adrenaline rush you might not be able to feel serious injury and you might be inclined to get up and continue the race which would only cause more damage and will result in longer recovery time form injury. Maybe "walking it off" stems from times which I didn't live in when people used to be more stupid and more "tough" on sports field.

Comment: @skyjur: "Less risk averse" is probably a much better characterization than "more stupid".

Comment: "less risk averse" is maybe more diplomatic, but to me it really is same as being more stupid. Also IQ is raising with every generation only to contribute to the factor that people used to be more stupid.

Comment: @skyjur: risk aversion is a matter of what your priorities are: what's a long sporting career worth to you compared with instant glory? This changes as the business changes. Intelligence is a matter of whether you can identify the best way to achieve your priorities, whatever they may be. Anyway, something that can be "walked off" is implied to be a minor issue, not even a real injury, just a temporary source of pain. The macho/stupid element comes in assuming that because you're a big tough guy, all injuries are minor to you. This isn't just low risk-aversion, it's wilful ignorance :-)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted answer is not quite right.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you could translate into a Chinese sports analogy (as this one is most applicable and familiar in the context of American football). Perhaps "If you get killed, keep swinging the ping-pong paddle!" would suffice.

Comment: _"as this one is most applicable and familiar in the context of American football"_ How's that then?

Comment: Best sports analogy ever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit For instance in soccer (non-American football) a player that is 'injured'(most likely faking it) during a play is expected to flail around as he collapses into spasms of horrific nightmare inducing pain.  In American football (non-American handegg) a player who is injured during the course of play is expected to 'walk it off' and continue playing as if nothing has happened in fear of giving any advantage to the opposing team a downed player might forfeit

Comment: Not quite sure that the phrase "to walk it off" has its origins in American Football.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow: if you watch soccer closely, you'll observe that *after* rolling around, and after the official's decision is made, the player gets up and often can be seen to literally walk off any pain they're experiencing: the pain of certain impacts really does abate somewhat with several paces or a short cautious run. So the phrase and the phenomenon are both familiar to those familiar with the sport. Naturally, to someone familiar with a different sport, they're more familiar in that other context.

Comment: The reason for this is that being kicked in the ankle does in point of fact hurt, regardless of the fact that as the game is officiated, the most effective way to win a free kick once you've been kicked in the ankle, is theatrics. Soccer is pretty much designed to frequently bring the various bony parts of the players into direct contact. Whereas your American football player is cleverly armored so that he can plausibly pretend to barely notice anything short of a torn ACL ;-) And tripping is fairly rare.

Comment: Is there some aversion in China nowadays to "Long March" references ?  Or perhaps homeopathic "quack/placebo" remedies are applied to pulled hamstrings and sprained ankles so routinely that nobody "walks it off".  Rubbing dirt on it counts as treatment. So does kissing it better.

Answer (score 7):

The implication of "walk it off" is not just ignore the problem and hope it gets better, but instead that the walking will actually be beneficial.

For example, in baseball, if someone is hit in the leg by a pitch is is much more reasonable to say "walk it off" than if they are hit in the arm or head.

For an older example, there is the 1736 play [Eurydice Hissed, or a Word to the Wise](https://books.google.com/books?id=QQMJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22walk%20it%20off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eLtUVb_ZKuixsAS2goCIDQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22walk%20it%20off%22&f=false):

> [Mr. Emphasis]: Why, faith, Jack, our Beer and Beer sat but ill on my Stomach so I got up to try to see if I could not walk it off.
>
> [unnamed character]: I wish I had any thing in my stomach to walk off...

Answer (score 5):

OED says *to walk off* is to "to get rid of (the effects of liquor, an ailment) by walking exercise."

Comment: While the myth of being able to "walk off" the effects of liquor has been completely busted, this definition also totally misses the context in which the statement is made.  Therefore the dictionary definition is invalid.  No part of what he was saying has anything to do with actual walking.

Comment: The dictionary definition certainly isn't invalid (and it's the sense I most associate with the phrase).  I'd say it's about as applicable to the quote: in all cases it juxtaposes the permanence of death with being able to "shake off" a "mild" impairment (drunk / injured / cramp).

Answer (score 5):

I wish to re-iterate Jander's comment.  "Walking it off" is sometimes actually better advice to an injury that isn't too serious.  Sometimes getting up and walking will produce circulation, and keep the injured area warm and limber.  If the area of injury is left to stiffen up, then the inflammation may get worse, and the injured party will continue to focus on the injury, which may increase suffering, possibly creating even more tension and inflammation.

My recollection is that, as a child in the '70s, usage was generally more literal, with 'mates trying to accurately evaluate whether walking it off was truly the better remedy.  Over time, humor seemed to take precedence, and nowadays I usually only hear it used sarcastically.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers giving the sports analogy where one "walks off" an injury (which incidentally is also used to show the officials that one will shortly be able to resume play), this could be a [fan shout out](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShoutOut).

Death in the comics is something that you might just "walk off". I can't find the issue right now, but when Rick Jones was trying to bring back his dead girlfriend, he asks a group of people "Who in this room has been dead before?" with everyone present raising their hands.

EDIT: [I asked about this issue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/107117/20774) on scifi.stackexchange and thanks to Richard I have an answer.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/107117/20774

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever been slammed around whether in a fight or something like a car wreck... then you may have been dazed. Walking around is like 'getting some fresh air' in that it can help you feel better. Moving around is better than just crumpling where you are... and may help you 'get it back together'. Of course, this is a joke because if you are killed 'walking it off' will not be an option...

Answer (score 0):

I recently voted to close a question that asked about the origin of the phrase "walk it off"—and the grounds given for closing that question were that it was a duplicate of this question and had an answer here. Under the circumstances, I thought I should provide an answer here that specifically addresses the question of when "walk it off" originated, and what sense or senses it had at that time.

In Google Books search results, the two earliest instances of "walk it off" occur within five years of one another, in books written by Henry Fielding and Samuel Richardson. Th earlier is Henry Fielding, [*The Historical Register: For the Year 1736*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QQMJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22walk+it+off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwB2oVChMI0fqPjf6qyAIVlESICh3TVgE-#v=onepage&q=%22walk%20it%20off%22&f=false) (1737):

> *1 Player.* Mr. *Emphasis*, good-morrow, you are early at the Rehearsal this Morning.
>
> *Emphasis.* Why, faith, *Jack*, our Beer and Beer [in later editions, *beef and beer* or *beer and beef*] sat but ill on my Stomach, so I got up to try if I could not **walk it off**.
>
> *1 Player.* I wish I had any thing in my Stomach to walk off ; if Matters do not go better with us shortly, my Teeth will forget their Office.

This is the same instance that DavePhD quotes in his answer, although he identifies it as being from *Eurydice Hissed*, a companion play to *The Historical Register*. Here, the walking is done in hopes of settling an upset stomach due to indigestion.

From Samuel Richardson, [*Pamela*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lcZiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA372&dq=%22walk+it+off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwADgKahUKEwjI4r6MgqvIAhXHRIgKHaPlAD4#v=onepage&q=%22walk%20it%20off%22&f=false) (1740):

> I had the Courage to take hold of his Arm, as if I had like to have slipt; For, thought I, thou shalt not see the Girl, worthy Friend, till I have talk'd to thee a little, if thou dost then.—Excuse me, Mr. H.—I hope I have not hurt my Foot!—I must lean upon you.
>
> Will you be pleased, Madam, to have a Chair? I fear you have sprain'd your Foot—Shall I help you to a Chair?
>
> No, no, Sir, I shall **walk it off**, if I hold by you.

Here is the more familiar (today) sense of walking off the effects of an injury or physical mishap. A similar instance appears in Jean-Baptiste Louvet de Couvray, [*Narrative of the Dangers to which I Have Been Exposed, Since the 31st of May, 1793*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vGlZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA159&dq=%22walk+it+off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwATgKahUKEwjI4r6MgqvIAhXHRIgKHaPlAD4#v=onepage&q=%22walk%20it%20off%22&f=false) (1795):

> I purposed to have pushed on much farther ; but I had not advanced above a mile, before I felt about my left heel an acute pain, which struck me at once like a flash of lightning. Hoping it would come to nothing, I endeavoured to **walk it off**: it became more acute, fixed, and extended under the sole of my foot. Probably it was an inflammatory humour, forming in consequence of my checked perspiration, which had been thrown upon my lungs at the moment when I fainted at the door of that woman, and which my late exertions had determined to the extremities.

To conclude, it appears that "walk it off" already had its still-current literal meaning of "walk in order to recover from some physical complaint, malady, or injury" in its earliest Google Books matches, from 1737 and 1740.

Answer (score -3):

To "walk it off" is an idiom from American baseball. For instance, a batter fouling a ball of his foot might be told that. Here's an example:

https://youtu.be/lkmYjBsjCFs

Comment: It's considered good form to provide a reference or other basis for any claim you make in an answer.